# Erro ao adicionar constraint (General error 1215) - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando criar duas tabelas relacionadas. Ao tentar 'migrar' elas, é retornado o erro:
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table 'companies' add constraint companies_taxregimeid_foreign' foreign key ('taxRegimeId') references 'tax_regimes'   ('id') on delete CASCADE)".

**Company - Model:**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'companies';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'taxRegimeId',
        'managerId',
    ];

    public function manager()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'managerId', 'id');
    }

    public function taxRegime()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TaxRegime','taxRegimeId', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Company - Migration:**

```
   <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCompaniesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('taxRegimeId')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('managerId')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('managerId')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        });

        Schema::table('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('taxRegimeId')->references('id')->on('tax_regimes')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('companies');
    }
}
```

Como dá pra ver no model, eu fiz como no 'managerId' que segue o mesmo esquema quanto ao relacionamento das entidades (Uma empresa tem um gestor (manager) | Uma empresa tem um regime de tributação (taxRegime)). No 'managerId' funciona corretamente, mas no 'taxRegimeId' dá esse problema que descrevi no início. O que pode ter causado este problema?

Comment: Tente jogar seu código `$table->foreign('taxRegimeId')->references('id')->on('tax_regimes')->onDelete('CASCADE');` dentro do callback do `Schema::create`

Comment: O erro persiste.

Comment: Você colocou as duas foreign keys? Outra pergunta, taxRegime e manager tem um relacionamento N:N? Se tiver você não pode fazer dessa forma com o belongsTo tem que fazer de acordo com a https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Sim, adicionei as duas forgein keys. O relacionamento de ambos é 1:N (Um gestor pode gerir várias empresas, um regime de tributação pode existir em várias empresas, isso é 1:N mesmo?).

Comment: Mas o mesmo regime não pode estar em várias empresas? Se sim, isso torna a relação N:N entre empresas e tributação.

Comment: Posso ter confundido mas, uma empresa tem somente um regime de tributação, mas o mesmo regime por existir em várias outras empresas. Pra mim isso é 1:N (FK na empresa)...

Comment: Entendi, bom o código parece estar OK. Você esta rodando o comando `migration:refresh'? Se tiver, ele não vai conseguir adicionar pq o seu método `down` está apenas dando um `dropifexists`, isso não da permissão de remover uma tabela com constraints adicionadas. Confira no seu banco, se a tabela já não existe. Não sei se é case sensitive, mas eu sempre coloquei o `CASCADE` em minúsculo, é uma outra tentativa.

Comment: achei o problema, a ordem das migrations afeta a execução. A migration de regime de tributação roda depois da de empresa. Quando roda a de empresa, ela não encontra a tabela de regime de tributação, ai dá o erro.